# Is it possible to publish a geoprocessing services that uses another dll?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have a functional model (Note:  not something from ArcGIS Model Builder) that is distributed as a compiled dll that I want to access via ArcGIS.

Right now I am writing python wrappers to communicate with the dll (convert the information in the features to the correct format for the dll, then convert the model output into formats for ArcGIS and my features).

Once I have finished that and have it running locally, is it possible to deploy the python code as a geoprocessing service, and the dll on the same server as the ArcGIS server, and have it all work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But the publishing process will NOT copy the dll. You'll get an analyzer error. You'll need to register the DLL directory with the datastore so ArcGIS Server doesn't try to copy it.

See [this link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/00178-data-value-used-by-value-cannot-be-copied-to-the-server.htm), it should be the error you get when trying to publish.

You'll probably want to use a replicated data store entry as it sounds like you are not working on the server machine itself. Lets assume that on your local machine the dll lives in `c:\staging`. You've put your dll on the ArcGIS Server machine at `c:\production\gpdlls`. Your replicated data store entry sets up using those two folders.

Comment: Awesome, the link was also helpful!